# How do I get each answer for each row with this conditional

Tags: python-2.7, date, pandas, dataframe

When I run this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('example.txt', parse_dates = [["DATE", "TIME"]], index_col=0)

b930 = df.HIGH.at_time("09:30:00")

print b930

a=0
if (b930 > 3046.00).any():
   a = 7
else:
   a = 10
print a
```

for this csv:

```
 DATE,TIME,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,VOLUME
 02/03/1997,09:30:00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,28 
 02/04/1997,09:30:00,3077.00,3078.00,3077.00,3077.50,280
 02/05/1997,09:30:00,3094.00,3094.50,3094.00,3094.00,50 
 02/06/1997,09:30:00,3106.00,3107.50,3106.00,3107.50,53
 02/07/1997,09:30:00,3144.00,3144.00,3143.50,3143.50,15 
 02/06/1997,16:20:00,3126.50,3126.50,3126.00,3126.00,24           
 02/06/1997,16:21:00,3126.50,3128.00,3126.50,3128.00,169          
 02/06/1997,16:22:00,3128.00,3128.00,3126.00,3126.00,243          
 02/06/1997,16:23:00,3125.50,3126.50,3125.50,3125.50,26
```

I get only one answer for 5 different rows. How would i get an answer for each row.

I've looked all over the internet.
I've tried couple of different versions of this.

```
df['logic'] = np.where(df['AAA'] > 5,'high','low'); df
```

I've tried all of these .empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Is it even possible am i close or just way off.

Thanks a lot, I don't know what I would do without this site or the community of very generous programmers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv('example.txt')
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.DATE + ' ' + df.TIME), inplace=True)
df.drop(['DATE', 'TIME'], axis=1, inplace=True)

>>> df
                       OPEN    HIGH     LOW   CLOSE  VOLUME
1997-02-03 09:30:00  3045.0  3045.0  3045.0  3045.0      28
1997-02-04 09:30:00  3077.0  3078.0  3077.0  3077.5     280
1997-02-05 09:30:00  3094.0  3094.5  3094.0  3094.0      50
1997-02-06 09:30:00  3106.0  3107.5  3106.0  3107.5      53
1997-02-07 09:30:00  3144.0  3144.0  3143.5  3143.5      15
1997-02-06 16:20:00  3126.5  3126.5  3126.0  3126.0      24
1997-02-06 16:21:00  3126.5  3128.0  3126.5  3128.0     169
1997-02-06 16:22:00  3128.0  3128.0  3126.0  3126.0     243
1997-02-06 16:23:00  3125.5  3126.5  3125.5  3125.5      26

>>> df.HIGH.at_time('9:30')
1997-02-03 09:30:00    3045.0
1997-02-04 09:30:00    3078.0
1997-02-05 09:30:00    3094.5
1997-02-06 09:30:00    3107.5
1997-02-07 09:30:00    3144.0
Name: HIGH, dtype: float64

a = 7 if (df.HIGH.at_time('09:30') > 3046).any() else 10

>>> a
7
```

I hate `map`, but it does the trick here:

```
>>> h.map(lambda x: 7 if x > 3046 else 10)
1997-02-03 09:30:00    10
1997-02-04 09:30:00     7
1997-02-05 09:30:00     7
1997-02-06 09:30:00     7
1997-02-07 09:30:00     7
Name: HIGH, dtype: int64
```

This is a terrible hack, but should be efficient:

```
true_val = 7
false_val = 10

>>> (df.HIGH.at_time('09:30') > 3046) * (false_val - true_val) + true_val
1997-02-03 09:30:00     7
1997-02-04 09:30:00    10
1997-02-05 09:30:00    10
1997-02-06 09:30:00    10
1997-02-07 09:30:00    10
Name: HIGH, dtype: int64
```

This gets you back a numpy array:

```
>>> np.where(df.HIGH.at_time("09:30:00") > 3046, 7, 10)
array([10,  7,  7,  7,  7])
```

Or you can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [7 if val > 3046 else 10 for val in df.HIGH.at_time("09:30:00")]
[10, 7, 7, 7, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

what does 'a' mean?
maybe you want

```
b930.map(lambda x: 7 if x>3046 else 10)
```

Comment: 'a' was something i thought i had to do to define a value to true and false i could be wrong idk.

Comment: @PhilChang I guess it should be rather `b930.map`, i.e. without `HIGH`, because `b930` is a series without a col name.